# In SQL remove duplicate groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

In SQL Server, I have the below data set after a query. I need to group this data by uid then remove "duplicates" and return the grouping with the most recent column D. I also need to return the 2 most recent deduplicated groups. A group is defined as a duplicate if:

- it has the same number of rows
- Columns A, B, C are the same
- the order of the rows is the same

| Uid | A | B | C | D1 | D2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 2021-02-19 | 2021-02-19 09:00:00 |
| 1 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 2021-02-19 | 2021-02-19 10:00:00 |
| 1 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 2021-02-19 | 2021-02-19 11:00:00 |
| 2 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 2021-01-19 | 2021-01-19 09:00:00 |
| 2 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 2021-01-19 | 2021-01-19 10:00:00 |
| 3 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 2020-02-19 | 2020-02-19 09:00:00 |
| 3 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 2020-02-19 | 2020-02-19 10:00:00 |
| 3 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 2020-02-19 | 2020-02-19 11:00:00 |
| 4 | 11 | 4 | 5 | 2000-10-05 | 2000-10-05 09:00:00 |

For example, in the above data set, uid's 1 and 3 are duplicates with 1 being the most recent. Hence the above data set should return

| Uid | A | B | C | D1 | D2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 2021-02-19 | 2021-02-19 09:00:00 |
| 1 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 2021-02-19 | 2021-02-19 10:00:00 |
| 1 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 2021-02-19 | 2021-02-19 11:00:00 |
| 2 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 2021-01-19 | 2021-01-19 09:00:00 |
| 2 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 2021-01-19 | 2021-01-19 10:00:00 |

I've tried the following window function:

```
FROM (

  SELECT 
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D1,
    D2,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by 
                                    Uid                                    
                                    ORDER BY D2 DESC) as rn
....

where rn = 1
```

but that does not allow me to group by uid. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Databases don't have a concept of "order" (except in the sense that you can order data by certain columns).  Looking at the above data, I get what you're saying about 3 being a duplicate of 1, but the concept of "same order" will fall apart, lacking some mechanism to actually tell the RDBMS what "order" means.  (Any query that lacks ORDER BY (with a enough values to provide uniqueness) on any set of data , may return the data in different orders when repeated.)

Comment: "the order of the rows is the same" -- how do you define the ordering of the rows? In the absence of explicit ordering, rows do not have inherent ordering.

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm defining order as meaning (6, 1, 2) then (6, 2, 1) then (6, 1, 2) would match (6, 1, 2) then (6, 2, 1) then (6, 1, 2) for another uid. (6, 1, 2) then (6, 1, 2) then (6, 2, 1) is a different order of the same 3 rows. How can I make the ordering explicit? Thank you

Comment: @ILikeCode "(6, 1, 2) then (6, 2, 1) then (6, 1, 2)" -- What result set ordering is that? Please define the rule. Seems to me you got the rows in that ordering just by luck.

Comment: @TheImpaler You are correct. I've updated the post to show the query that I'm using to get the first output. I'm not sure how to get the second output. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below query the subquery temp creates a comma seperated column for A, B, C. Then I am using partition on A, B, C and getting a rank based on date at subquery temp2 level. The final query on the outside pulls only the rank 1 and shows the output from your table.

```
select t.Uid, t.A,t.B, t.C , t.D1, t.D2
from (
                    select Uid, A,B,C, D1, rank() over ( partition by A, B,C order by D1 desc) as rank
                    from 
                        (SELECT Uid,  
                    A=STUFF  
                    (  
                         (  
                           SELECT  ', ' + CAST(A AS VARCHAR(MAX))  
                           FROM Table1 t2   
                           WHERE t2.Uid = t1.Uid   
                           FOR XML PATH('')  
                         ),1,1,''  
                    )  ,
                    B=STUFF  
                    (  
                         (              
                           SELECT  ', ' + CAST(B AS VARCHAR(MAX))  
                           FROM Table1 t2   
                           WHERE t2.Uid = t1.Uid   
                           FOR XML PATH('')  
                         ),1,1,''  
                    )  ,
                    C=STUFF  
                    (  
                         (  
                           SELECT  ', ' + CAST(C AS VARCHAR(MAX))  
                           FROM Table1 t2   
                           WHERE t2.Uid = t1.Uid   
                           FOR XML PATH('')  
                         ),1,1,''  
                    )  ,
                    cast (max( [D1] ) as date) D1
                    FROM Table1 t1  
                    GROUP BY Uid  ) as temp 
                    ) as temp2
join Table1 t on temp2.Uid = t.Uid
and temp2. D1= t.D1
where temp2.rank = 1
```

Here is the DB Fiddle link : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=de2127330c2e60d3733bfc9548504142

Comment: Thank you [Raseena Abdul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15155142/raseena-abdul). In my situation the resultset is the result of a large query involving multiple tables. Is there a way I could replace Table1 with this resultset? Thank you

Comment: Can you save your output to a temporary table? I am using the stuff/xml path to create a comma separate file to compare multiple rows. Then I am using the output to show your original values. So essentially you need your output twice. Also, if you are using SQL Server 2017 or higher you can use STRING_AGG function for create a comma separated file. : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a790248d2bcb5572d8e326928c2d8496